# How can a beginner start an investment portfolio in Europe (France)?

Tags: investing, portfolio, eur-euro, european-union, france

I have been lurking, reading information about personal finances for a few months (if not years) now, but I didn't get the chance to start because I don't know where to start.

Here is the thing: I am French, young (19), and have a little bit of money saved, and I'd like to start setting up a portfolio with, say, 1000€. I'd also like to be able to add some money to it on a regular basis.

I know I should look for a broker, but the information I found is for U.S. people. I think that from France I would have to pay currency conversion stuff, and that doesn't seem good.

If anyone here is French, or simply knows or has advice on how to start a portfolio when you're French, that would be awesome.

I am looking for mostly moderate-risk investments for now. I don't know if this is realistic as a beginner, but 5% profit seems a fine start to me.

p.s. I know there are already some questions about starting, but my question is more about the specific point of being French (European) and what it implies.

Comment: Surely if you have been reading information you should be able to find some good books about investing in France, or information on you local Stock Exchange website. I think these would be good places to start for you.

Comment: There are actually very few informations about this in french. There are blogs about what and where to invest, but not on how to actually start, like what are trusted brokers or things like that.

Comment: Your local Stock Exchange should have a list of brokers registered to trade different products in your country (and other information), but I don't think they would make recommendations on the brokers. It is up to you to select one that suits your requirements and you feel comfortable with.

Comment: I forgot to ask in my last comment: What do you mean by "local Stock Exchange" ? I don't know what website this could refer to.

Comment: http://www.boursedeparis.fr/

Comment: Yes a few minutes on the net from Australia I found [Boursedeparis.fr](http://www.boursedeparis.fr/) as well. I am sure you could easily have done this.

Comment: By the way your local index is the **CAC 40**.

Comment: I probably didn't use the good keywords, and didn't really know what to look for. But thanks, this seems to be a good starting point. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Malharhak - I just typed in "French Stock Exchange" !

Answer (score 4):

This post has been wrote in 2014, so if you read this text be aware.

At the time, and since France does tax a lot investment, I'd suggest you start a PEA and filling in using the lazy investment portfolio. That means buying European and/or French ETFs & index, and hold them as long as you can.

You can fill your PEA (Plan d'Epargne en Action) up to 150.000€ for a period of at least 8 years as long as you fill it with European and French stocks. After the period of 8 years your profit is taxed at only mere 15%, instead of the 33% you see in a raw broker account.

Since you are young, I think a 100% stocks is something you can hold on. If you can't sleep at night with 100% stocks, take some bonds up to 25%, even more.

Anyway, the younger you start investing, the more ahead you may eventually go.